# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies - app bundle delete

Tags: android, google-play-console, policy, android-app-bundle

I want to disable my previous releases on play console because they had a **google policy** issue (related to **the background location access**). So I did disable that access in my application and uploaded a new release of my app.

The problem is that I always get the same rejection message of my application whenever I try to publish it; for example on a **closed test**. even though that I had disable the background location access and uploaded a new **version code**. And the message says that one of my previous releases does not respect google policy.

When I check the **app bundle explorer** I find this:
[image]

Even by discarding those releases, I always found related versions in **actives status**.

I want a way to disable them or delete them so I can avoid the google rejection error.

Bellow is a screenshot of the **rejection** **email**:
[image]

Comment: Are you selecting the option of including the previous bundle while submitting a new one?

Comment: where is this option ? as I know when I create a new release, all I do is upload a new application in the app bundle section..I can't find this option

Answer (score 1):

Could you reverify if you are including the previous build versions while submitting a new app bundle. Please take a look at the `Not Included` section in the image below.

If you are choosing `include` that could be one of the reasons for rejection.

[image]

In your Google Play Console navigate to `Production -> Create a new release/Edit Release`. You will be see an option to include.

In case of submitted versions `Navigate to production -> Releases -> View Release Details -> Retained app bundles` to verify what was included. Refer to the below image.

[image]

Also, as a quick check see what are the version codes included in your latest public release. Refer below image

If you observe I have 2 version codes active - 32 and 21

[image]

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment, could you give me the path where to find this information on google play console?

Comment: In your Google Play Console navigate to Production -> Create a new release/Edit Release. This is make a new version. 

In case of submitted versions Navigate to production -> Releases -> View Release Details -> Retained app bundles

Comment: No there is nothing included in my latest version, indeed I tried to delete the app bundle => save and then discard release, but nothing changed..I still get the status as active for the version causing the problem

Comment: May be not in the latest release but you may have included it in one of your previous releases and still it's active. I have 32 versions of my app bundle yet only 32 and 21 version codes are active. It's because I have that in one of my versions.

In your case it's just 5 & 3

Comment: May i ask one question about the retained app bundle. I have a similar retained app bundle just like this example, but it's useless any more and I do not know why it became retained status. Is there any way to deactivate that retained app bundle?
I cannot find any deactivate button.